crystal report generate using dataset and pass parameters from report to code
I have a visual studio project which shows reports using crystal reports. Previously in this project crestal reports directly connected to Sql sever database so when the user wants to see a report they call the report and crystal report handles the rest. this makes ever user need to have access to the database to view a report now I need to modify this project so data comes through a dataset using a web api.
I converted most of the reports with out any question but when it comes to the reports which are based on stored procedure I couldn't find a way to pass the parameters to database. In this project previously those parameters were taken by the crystal report and generate data according to stored procedure now there is a dataset as data source. so I want to know a way to pass the parameters to the code.

both of these tables created to two sp in their respective names
